# Pytest: customize short test summary info, remove filepath

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to get more useful output from `pytest -tb=no` short output. I have integration tests stored in JSON files, so the output all looks extremely similar.

```
tests/test_dit_cli.py .......F............................. [ 29%]
...F...F.FF........F............................F...FFFFFFF [ 75%]
FFF.F..................F.....FF                             [100%]

===================== short test summary info =====================
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json7] - assert "Lin...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json40] - assert "Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json44] - assert "Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json46] - assert "Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json47] - assert "Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json56] - assert "Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json85] - assert "Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json89] - AssertionE...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json90] - AssertionE...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json91] - AssertionE...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json92] - AssertionE...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json93] - AssertionE...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json94] - AssertionE...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json95] - AssertionE...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json96] - assert 'Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json97] - assert 'Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json98] - assert "Li...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json100] - Assertion...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json119] - assert "L...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json125] - Assertion...
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json126] - Assertion...
================= 21 failed, 106 passed in 2.94s ==================
```

Seeing this same `tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[dit_json126]` 20 times doesn't help me get a gauge on what's going wrong in the project, so I usually just fix errors one test at a time. Each test entry has extra information about the type of test being run and the expected outcome, but I don't know how to get that information into pytest. I would hope for something like this:

```
===================== short test summary info =====================
FAILED [func, vanilla Python] - assert "Li...
FAILED [Thing, value assignment] - assert "Li...
FAILED [TypeMismatch, String var assigned to List] - assert "Lin...
```

I actually got close to this, by providing a value for `ids` in the `parametrize` call.

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc: Metafunc):
    for fixture in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if fixture == "dit_json":
            test_dicts = list(load_from_json())
            titles = [test_dict["title"] for test_dict in test_dicts]
            metafunc.parametrize(argnames=fixture, argvalues=test_dicts, ids=titles)
```

```
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[TypeMismatch, List var assigned to String]
FAILED tests/test_dit_cli.py::test_dits[import, anon import referenced in list assignment]
```

So, I'm really close, I just want to remove the filepath, so that the line is shorter. Is there a way to change the filepath of where it thinks the tests are located? Or a hook that would let me arbitrarily modify the summary output? I tried modifying `pytest_collection_modifyitems` and changing `item.fspath`, but it didn't change anything in the output. I've seen ways to modify lots of other things about the output, but nothing regarding specifically that filepath.

Comment: You can set the environment variable `COLUMNS` to a higher value to get longer lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to shorten the nodeids in the short summary info, you can overwrite the `nodeid` attribute of the `report` object. A simple example:

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    report.nodeid = "..." + report.nodeid[-10:]
```

placed in your `conftest.py`, will truncate each nodeid to its last ten chars:

```
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED ...st_spam[0] - assert False
FAILED ...st_spam[1] - assert False
FAILED ...st_spam[2] - assert False
FAILED ...st_spam[3] - assert False
FAILED ...st_spam[4] - assert False
FAILED ...:test_eggs - assert False
```

If you want a fully customized short test summary lines, you need to implement a custom `TerminalReporter` and replace the vanilla one early enough in the test run. Example stub:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.terminal import TerminalReporter


class MyReporter(TerminalReporter):
    def short_test_summary(self):
        # your own impl goes here, for example:
        self.write_sep("=", "my own short summary info")
        failed = self.stats.get("failed", [])
        for rep in failed:
            self.write_line(f"failed test {rep.nodeid}")


@pytest.mark.trylast
def pytest_configure(config):
    vanilla_reporter = config.pluginmanager.getplugin("terminalreporter")
    my_reporter = MyReporter(config)
    config.pluginmanager.unregister(vanilla_reporter)
    config.pluginmanager.register(my_reporter, "terminalreporter")
```

This will produce a summary section like

```
========================== short test summary info ===========================
failed test tests/test_spam.py::test_spam[0]
failed test tests/test_spam.py::test_spam[1]
failed test tests/test_spam.py::test_spam[2]
failed test tests/test_spam.py::test_spam[3]
failed test tests/test_spam.py::test_spam[4]
failed test tests/test_spam.py::test_eggs
```

Note that the above impl of `MyReporter.short_test_summary()` is not complete and only put for demonstration purposes! For a reference, check out the [`pytest` impl](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/8d16bec3297aed652bf0c3ad5835499e793c456f/src/_pytest/terminal.py#L1081-L1124).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was able to remove the filepath with the `report.nodeid` edit, that was perfect. A question tho, TerminalReporter is marked as `@final`, and Pylance instantly complained about it. I'm not sure how I could implement my own TR if I can't subclass, unless I just redo that whole thing from scratch.

Comment: @IsaiahShiner that's unfortunate - looks like the changes were introduced in [#7780](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/7780), so 6.1 and upwards are affected. A questionable decision IMO since e.g. `pytest-sugar` is completely built around subclassing the reporter. Anyway, [`@typing.final`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.final) is only for type checkers and ignored at runtime, so there shouldn't be any issue with subclassing; I would just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 3):

@IsaiahShiner

As for `@final` issue, You can do something like:

```
from _pytest.terminal import TerminalReporter


MyReporter = type('MyReporter', (TerminalReporter, ), {})

def __init__(self, config, file=None):
  super(MyReporter, self).__init__(config, file)

MyReporter.__init__ = __init__
```

Not looking nice, but works.