# How to override a long file path in pytest summary report

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to remove long file paths from pytests summary report. For example:

```
========== short test summary info ==========
FAILED ../../../../../more/directories/here/tests/test_something.py::test_something
FAILED ../../../../../more/directories/here/tests/test_something.py::test_something
FAILED ../../../../../more/directories/here/tests/test_something.py::test_something
```

I want to have control over the file path and maybe just print the filename on its own:

```
========== short test summary info ==========
FAILED test_something.py::test_something
FAILED test_something.py::test_something
FAILED test_something.py::test_something
```

I read about the `pytest_runtest_logreport` hook on [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526149/pytest-customize-short-test-summary-info-remove-filepath) talking about reducing the length of the nodeid by adding the following to `conftest.py` but this doesn't quite do what I want.

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    report.nodeid = "..." + report.nodeid[-10:]
```

Output:

```
========== short test summary info ==========
FAILED ../../../../../..._something
FAILED ../../../../../..._something
FAILED ../../../../../..._something
```

I then looked at the API docs and I see that the `TestReport` class has a `location` property. So I tried to override this with `None`.

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    report.location = None
```

But this didn't change the output at all.

I also tried to override the first element in the Tuple (the filesystempath element) with a blank string.

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    report.location = ("", report.location[1], report.location[2])
```

But this again did nothing to change the output in any way.

There must be a way to control this and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Setup :

```py
root/
  so71126638_a_very_very_long_name_for_a_directory_which_would_be_sufficient_to_trigger_the_length_limit/
    with_a_nested_directory_which_also_has_a_long_and_boring_name/
      test_so71126638.py
```

```py
# file: so71126638_a_very_very_long_name_for_a_directory_which_would_be_sufficient_to_trigger_the_length_limit/with_a_nested_directory_which_also_has_a_long_and_boring_name/test_so71126638.py
def test_failure():
    assert False
```

```sh
$ pytest
FAILED so71126638_a_very_very_long_name_for_a_directory_which_would_be_sufficient_to_trigger_the_length_limit/with_a_nested_directory_which_also_has_a_long_and_boring_name/test_so71126638.py::test_failure - assert False
```

Adding the `conftest.py` in the root directory :

```py
# file: conftest.py
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    report.nodeid = "..." + report.nodeid[-10:]
```

```sh
$ pytest
FAILED ...st_failure - assert False
```

The truncation is very crude (only the 10 last characters, including the 3 for `.py`). We can do better :

```py
# file: conftest.py
from pathlib import Path
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    report.nodeid = ".../" + Path(report.nodeid).name
```

```sh
$ pytest
FAILED .../test_so71126638.py::test_failure - assert False
```

Or even better :

```py
# file: conftest.py
from pathlib import Path
NODEID_LENGTH_TRESHOLD = 60

def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    if len(report.nodeid) > NODEID_LENGTH_TRESHOLD:
        report.nodeid = ".../" + Path(report.nodeid).name
```

so that by adding another test file :

```py
# file: so71126638_short/test_so71126638_short.py
def test_other_failure():
    assert False and False
```

```sh
$ pytest
FAILED .../test_so71126638.py::test_failure - assert False
FAILED so71126638_short/test_so71126638_short.py::test_other_failure - assert (False)
```