# 'Customize' short test summary info pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, assert

I'm starting to learn automated testing.
When I run a test I want to get a specific text ('No Add to Cart button') on error of selenium NoSuchElementException

I'm trying smth of that:

```
class TestCart:
    def test_check_btn(self, browser):
        browser.get(link)
        browser.implicitly_wait(5)
        assert browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.no-such-btn') is not None, 'No Add to Cart button'
```

Here is an actual log

```
=============================================================================== short test summary info =============================================================================== 
FAILED test_cart/test_items.py::TestCart::test_check_btn - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css sele...
```

How can I replace the error message with what I want?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the error with try/except and `raise Exception` with your message. Your error is happening before the assertion. To modify the text of the short summary you can to use a hook or a [TerminalReporter override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65541513/11799308).

[Locating Elements by CSS Selectors](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) does not return `None` it throws `NoSuchElementException`

```py
class TestCart:
    def test_check_btn(self, browser):
        browser.get(link)
        browser.implicitly_wait(5)

        try:
            browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.no-such-btn')
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException as e:
            raise Exception('No Add to Cart button') from None
```

Inside `conftest.py`.

```py
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import pytest
    import _pytest._code.code

def pytest_runtest_logreport(report: 'pytest.TestReport'):
    if report.failed:
        try:
            chain: '_pytest._code.code.ExceptionChainRepr' = report.longrepr.chain
            repr_file_location: '_pytest._code.code.ReprFileLocation' = chain[-1][1]
            repr_file_location.message = 'My Message: ' + repr_file_location.message.removeprefix('Exception:')
        except Exception:
            import traceback
            import sys
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
```

[image]