# pytest - How to hide amount of deselected tests

Tags: python, pytest, summary

I'm working on a project that has a lot of different testcases and we use different tags to organize the test sets that we want to execute.

I was wondering if there is any way to hide the amount of "deselected tests" that appear in the summary report. I mean the `103 deselected` part

```py
===================================== short test summary info ======================================
PASSED test_server.py::test_init1
PASSED test_server.py::test_init2
PASSED test_server.py::test_init3
PASSED test_server.py::test_init4
PASSED test_server.py::test_init5
PASSED test_server.py::test_invalid_init
PASSED test_server.py::test_concurrent_init
=========================== 7 passed, 103 deselected, 1 warning in 3.12s ===========================
```

I've seen other posts were they explain how to change the [TestingReport from pytest so the summary is as you wish it to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526149/pytest-customize-short-test-summary-info-remove-filepath) but after all I only want to hide that info. There is any shortcut way to do it that I might have skipped in the docs?